# What URL encoding is used with this XML?

Tags: php, xml, encoding, urlencode, url-encoding

I have an xml and I want to send it as parameters in a GET method. I want the XML to look something like this:

```
<%3Fxml+version%3D"1.0"+encoding%3D"UTF-8"+%3F>%0D%0A%0D%0A<lead>%0D%0A+++<mode>LIVE<%2Fmode>%0D%0A%09<title>Mrs<%2Ftitle>%0D%0A%09<firstname>Hannah<%2Ffirstname>%0D%0A%09<lastname>Dwindle<%2Flastname>%0D%0A%09<id>1723658492165<%2Fid>%0D%0A%09<homecode><%2Fhomecode>%0D%0A%09<hometel><%2Fhometel>%0D%0A%09<workcode>011<%2Fworkcode>%0D%0A%09<worktel>132189<%2Fworktel>%0D%0A%09<mobile>0824176239<%2Fmobile>%0D%0A%09<email>hannahdwindle@gmail.com<%2Femail>%0D%0A%09<comment>THIS+IS+A+COMMENT<%2Fcomment>%0D%0A%09<source>UPSTART<%2Fsource>%0D%0A%09<notes>THIS+I+A+NOTE<%2Fnotes>%0D%0A%09<language>E<%2Flanguage>%0D%0A%09<product>P<%2Fproduct>%0D%0A<%2Flead>%0D%0A+++++++++
```

I have tried urlencode() and rawurlencode() but it did not give me the output that I wanted.

Comment: maybe you should use str_replace to get what you wanted

Comment: Please post an example of what you're starting with, and what you get out of urlencode() so we can see what is "wrong".